# SIFT Feature Extraction

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction, sift

Firstly, English is not my native language hence sorry for my grammar mistakes in advance. I am trying to implement the SIFT feature extraction algorithm. I have couple of question which are not very clear at paper:

1. What happens at octave boundries when we are searching for local maxima? Do we search just 8+9 neighborhood or create extra layers that we dont use at other steps?
2. When interpolating the extremas with 2nd order func., do we upscale the downscaled images directly from DoG or interpolate at original downsampled image than upscale for the subpixel accuracy pixel positions?
3. When interpolating the extremas with 2nd order func., is it at same octave or other octaves are used? I think other octaves must be upsampled before interpolating?
4. Should image size stay same after convolving with the Gaussian? This will effect the keypoint locations.

Vevaldi provided great implementation http://vision.ucla.edu/~vedaldi/code/sift.html . Because it is at .mex format i can't reach what is going on inside. Other open source codes' solutions haven't satisfy me also. Hence i am asking for your help.

Thank you so much for your valuable answers.

Comment: I think you are on the wrong site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to a http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answers:)